# Failed For Listen Port 80 (Serveo and SSH)

Tags: ssh, domain, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create a very simple one page website hosted on my PC. I have used Python and SimpleHTTPServer to host the server on `localhost:8080` and am now trying to forward traffic from a domain to localhost. For this I am using 
[Serveo](https://serveo.net/). Everything works great when I use this command to forward the ports:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R 80:localhost:8080 serveo.net
```

But the moment I include my domain and run this command:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R mydomain.ml:80:localhost:8080 serveo.net
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 80
```

I have done some research on the error and found that it is mostly caused by something else using that port, but there is nothing else on my PC or at the domain. In the DNS Manager of my domain I have made sure that I have an A record that points to `159.89.214.31` and a TXT record with the fingerprint of my SSH key as needed by Serveo.

What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to specify an numerical IP address of remote server your connection should bind to, not symbolic address. If that works, check remote hosts file, i.e. that remote server knows what mydomain.ml is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself just by waiting, I belive the DNS Manager was still in the process of setting the records.